# email zend framwork smtp html

Tags: html, zend-framework, email, smtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending email via SMTP on zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700470/sending-email-via-smtp-on-zend-framework)

```
     $smtpHost = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
                $mail = new Zend_Mail();
                $mail->setBodyText($form->getValue('body'));
                $mail->setBodyHtml('<a href = "http://localhost:8080/certificate/certificate-image/id/' . $id . '"></a>');
                $mail->setFrom($certtime['email'], $certtime['first_name'] . $certtime['last_name']);
                $mail->addTo($form->getValue('reciever'));
                $mail->setSubject('My Certificate');
                $mail->send($smtpHost);
```

this code works fine but i cannot send html content or it is not working i dont know why