# Send email using gmail smtp in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [email zend framwork smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700470/email-zend-framwork-smtp)

I have following configuration:

```
smtp.type = Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp
smtp.smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtp.username = "ddd@gmail.com"
smtp.password = "dddd"
smtp.email = "ddd@gmail.com"
smtp.port = "587"
smtp.ssl = "tls"
smtp.auth = "login"
```

I am getting following error:

```
5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 74sm813723wem.41
```

My COde:

```
public function sendEmail( $mailData, $bootstrap = null ) {

        // Get SMTP server configurations
        if ( $bootstrap == null ) {
            $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
            $bootstrap = $front->getParam('bootstrap');
        }
        $smtpSettings = $bootstrap->getOption('smtp');

        print_r($smtpSettings);

        // Only pass username password settings if the authentication is required.
        if ( $smtpSettings['auth'] == 'login' ) {

            $config = array('ssl' => $smtpSettings['ssl'],
                        'username' => $smtpSettings['username'],
                        'password' => $smtpSettings['password']);

            $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp( $smtpSettings['smtpServer'], $config );
        } else {
            $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp( $smtpSettings['smtpServer'] );
        }

        $mail = new Zend_Mail( 'utf-8' );

        try {

            if ( $mailData['user'] == true ) { 
                $mail->setFrom( $mailData['from'], $mailData['fromName'] );

            } else {
                  $mail->setFrom( $smtpSettings['email'], "eCHDP" );
            }

            // Do we have a single reciepent or multiple receipents?
            if ( !is_array($mailData['to']) ) {
                $mail->addTo( $mailData['to'] , $mailData['toName'] );
            } else {
                // We have multiple receipents. Add all of them.
                foreach ( $mailData['to'] as $id => $value ) {
                    $mail->addTo( $value , $mailData['toName'][$id] );
                }
            }

            $mail->setSubject( $mailData['subject'] );
            $mail->setBodyHtml( $mailData['body'] );

            // If attachment found then attach
            if ( $mailData['attachment'] ) {
                $attach = new Zend_Mime_Part( file_get_contents( $mailData['attachment'] ) );
                $attach->type = 'application/pdf';
                $attach->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
                $attach->filename = 'Invoice.pdf';
                $mail->addAttachment( $attach );
            }

            $mail->send( $transport );

            return true;

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            echo "Error sending Email : ";
            $logger = Zend_Registry::get('Logger');
            $logger->err($e->getMessage());
            echo $e->getMessage() . "\n\n\n";
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Can someone guess that what is the error ? I can post code as well if required.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that you must issue a STARTTLS command first ;) No, seriously: you are using `ssl = ssl`, you should try `ssl = tls` - those are two different methods of securing the connection to the server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is from our application.ini

```
resources.mail.transport.type = Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp
resources.mail.transport.host = "smtp.gmail.com"
resources.mail.transport.port = 587
resources.mail.transport.auth = "login"
resources.mail.transport.username = "email@address.com"
resources.mail.transport.password = "password"
resources.mail.transport.ssl = "tls"
```

And it "Just works (tm)"!

Comment: OK. Let me try this but where are you using this `resources.mail.transport.type` ??

Comment: Ehh.. in application.in :) Do you use ONLY Zend_Mail or is it a fullblown ZF site? http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html
Anyways, you should be able to use our config values in your specifications.

Comment: The mail resource simply autoregister to Zend_Mail when used with Zend MVC as a mail transport

Comment: I tried this setting and error is changed: `5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at                              
 5.5.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 h43sm824480wes.35
`

Comment: @Phliplip: I am running it in Zend environment but I dont have `"resources.mail.transport.type = Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp
"` in my application.ini

Comment: This means wrong username/password combination.

Comment: I am using correct username/password combination. I am successfully login to gmail using my username and password.

Comment: If you paste your mail sending code. May be it will help me..

Comment: @Awan: What if you paste your code, then we can help you :)

Comment: OK review my question again...

Comment: @Awan: You need to add **port** and **auth** to your `$config` array. auth is the authentificationType used. In this case 'login', it could be 'digest' in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with: `ssl = tls` or `port = 587`