# Transport for Zend email

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to PHP and Zend.

I am trying to figure out what smtp server is used in some application. It has only the following code and does not apply anywhere transport setup (e.g. Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp). I also looked through application.ini etc. I am trying to find out what is a username and password for this app. Any suggestions where this information might be stored ?

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom(Zend_Registry::get('config')->app->contact->email);
$mail->addTo($this->getUscEmail(), $this->getFirstName().' '.$this->getLastName());
$mail->addCc(Zend_Registry::get('config')->app->contact->email, 'SOWK FWS');
$mail->setSubject('Workstudy Documentation - '.$this->getFirstName().' '.$this->getLastName());
$mail->setBodyText('Hi '.$this->getFirstName().",\r\n".'Congratulations on completing your Orientation!);
$mail->send();
```

**EDIT 1:**
This part of my application.ini file:

```
##Application
app.invalid_login.max = 3
app.invalid_login.wait = 10
app.contact.email = cccc@ccc.com
app.admin.email = aaaaan@aaa.com
app.number_questions_to_ask.max = 5 
app.data_path  = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/" 
app.pdf_path  = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/PDF/" 

 ##Session
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 3600
resources.session.name = "Work_Study"
```

php.ini :

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = email.ccc.com

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com
sendmail_from = example@ccc.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =
```

And this is an output when I print transport object before using it to send email:

```
Transport ==> object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail)#215 (12) {
  ["subject"]=>
  NULL
  ["parameters"]=>
  NULL
  ["EOL"]=>
  string(2) "
"
  ["_errstr:protected"]=>
  NULL
  ["body"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["boundary"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["header"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["_headers:protected"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_isMultipart:protected"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_mail:protected"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_parts:protected"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["recipients"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they are not using SMTP and relying on the `Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail`. This is the default in ZF1 (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.introduction.html)

The `Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail` implementation uses the php `mail` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and I don't think that supports SMTP with authentication.

So looks like you will need to modify the code to use the `Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp` transport.

If you need help setting up the SMTP transport, you can refer to this previous question: [Send email using gmail smtp in zend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453610/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-in-zend)

Comment: Thanks. Even if it is using default Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail, It should have some email server configuration and user. However, if I remove that server configuration from php.ini, it is still sending emails. So, it is using something else. I need to find a user configuration too. I added some more information to the post.

Comment: Maybe you can check Bootstrap.php for your app. The SMTP transport could be set there. Additionally you can try a search for `Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp` and see if it shows up in your app.

Comment: Nope. Nothing. I checked it already. I tried also to debug, and to print out from Zend object on email is sent. I put the output example above. Server, where this app is running, does not have any smtp service running. I am out of options how to track down.

Comment: Try creating a test page and `echo phpinfo()` to test if your SMTP settings in really disabled. Maybe another php.ini file is overriding your changes or taking precedence.